# Read Pop email in c# using Openpop

Tags: c#, pop3, openpop

I am trying to read pop messages in c# using openpop.While the messages are getting downloaded , they are also getting marked as "READ" on server when i use getMessage function.

Is there any way where I could just download the message and it remains as unread in the mailbox.

Comment: I guess that's not the fault of OpenPOP.net because pop3 doesn't even support marking on servers.

Answer (score 0):

Pop3 protocol doesn't have flags. So, a message on a server cannot be marked as Readed. Flags are supported by IMAP.

if you can change "openpop" to another library, i recommend "https://github.com/bertjohnson/OpaqueMail"